# Netlogo: How can i write code so if there are no turtles it automatically sprouts one?

Tags: netlogo

For example if a turtle just died and there are no more turtles, i want my code to sprout another turtle
is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if not any? turtles` [ create or whatever you want to be done ]

But you will have to put this code wherever you think it might happen. Or perhaps put it in your main loop so that it checks once each tick. I don't believe there is any way to have a sort of dynamic monitor that constantly checks.